# Как правильно реализовать прокручиваемый блок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Необходимо вставить на страницу блок с ссылками, который можно скроллить, если блок не помещается на страницу. Понятно, что делается с помощью `overflow: auto;`. Когда использовал табличную верстку, все работало нормально (только почему-то скролл вылезал за границы блока). Сейчас делаю верстку с помощью гридов.

Макет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При большом списке ссылок в tag-list скролл появляется не для блока tag-list, а для всей страницы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы получить результат вида (табличная верстка)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать. Спасибо.

Код

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Consolas, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
            'header'
            'main'
            'footer';
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: #00d3ec; /*delete*/
}

.main {
    grid-area: main;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
            'tag-list tag-info';
    /*grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: #00d3ec; /*delete*/
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    display: block;
}

.sub-gird {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
            'tag-list tag-info';
    grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.tag-list {
    grid-area: tag-list;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.tag-list > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tag-info {
    grid-area: tag-info;
}

.tag-info > table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <header class="header">
        <p style="text-align: center">Header</p>
    </header>

    <main class="main">

<!--        <div class="sub-grid">-->

            <div class="tag-list">
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
            </div>

            <div class="tag-info">
                <table>
                    <tr><th>Параметр</th><th>Значение</th></tr>
                </table>
            </div>

<!--        </div>-->

    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
        <p style="text-align: center">Footer</p>
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решено. Нужно скрыть скролл для `.main`

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Consolas, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
            'header'
            'main'
            'footer';
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: #00d3ec; /*delete*/
}

.main {
    grid-area: main;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
            'tag-list tag-info';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden; /*с auto тоже работает*/
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: #00d3ec; /*delete*/
}

.tag-list {
    grid-area: tag-list;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.tag-list > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tag-info {
    grid-area: tag-info;
}

.tag-info > table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <header class="header">
        <p style="text-align: center">Header</p>
    </header>

    <main class="main">

<!--        <div class="sub-grid">-->

            <div class="tag-list">
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
                <a href="#">tag1</a>
            </div>

            <div class="tag-info">
                <table>
                    <tr><th>Параметр</th><th>Значение</th></tr>
                </table>
            </div>

<!--        </div>-->

    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
        <p style="text-align: center">Footer</p>
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Хорошо бы в ответ поместить не фрагмент, а полный код. Чтобы можно было посмотреть как работает, тогда и больше положительного отклика получите :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, обновлено